# Combine elements from ArrayLists

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, colors

I know that some answers have been provided for similar questions, but none of them seemed to be suitable for my issue. I'm making a program to generate images for Granny Squares, or squares that have different color rings on the inside.

The user is able to select how many rings there are, and therefore the number of colors necessary will change. Therefore, I cannot use nested for loops to go through each color as the number of for loops would have to change. Is there a way I can create combinations for these colors?

For example, if I used the colors White, Blue, and Green, the following combinations would be White, White, White; White, White, Blue; White, White, Green; White, Blue, White; etc. So is there a way to accomplish this without nested for loops?

Comment: Why exactly can't you use nested loops? If you have your squares in a structure like a `List<List<Colour>>` you could easily do something like `for(List<Colour> colours : squares) { for(Colour colour : colours) { ... } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an algorithm that achieves this using recursion.

```
public static void combine(List<Character> colors, List<Character> combination) {
    if (combination.size() == colors.size()) {
        System.out.println(combination);
    } else {
        for (char color : colors) {
            combination.add(color);
            combine(colors, combination);
            combination.remove(combination.size() - 1);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Character> colors = new ArrayList<>();
    colors.add('W');
    colors.add('B');
    colors.add('G');

    combine(colors, new LinkedList<Character>());
}
```

`colors` is the original list of colors (W, B, G)

`combinations` is a list that is continually modified throughout the recursion to hold the current combination.

Here is what happens to `combination` until it first hits the base case

```
[W] // add W, call recursively 
[W, W] // add W, call recursively 
[W, W, W] // add W, call recursively
```

The base case is now met, and it prints `[W, W, W]`.  It then removes the last color we put in the list, W, and adds the next color in `colors` to `combination`, which gives `[W, W, B]`.  The base case is met again so it prints it out.

It continues to do this until all combinations have been printed.